# jQuery/JavaScript preventing duplicate appends

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

seemingly minor issue I'm having with a mock-forum system I'm trying to prototype, as the following array and table function I've created duplicates a forum table the screen due to the appends I've used, and I'm not sure how to go about avoiding this or amending this (I.e, if the user repetitively clicks the forum page, the forum will repetitively generate). I'm still fairly knew to the language, but from what I've found from similar posts, everything I tried to apply hasn't resolved the issue.

```
var index;    

var topics = [      
    {title: "Football Topics", followers: 280, articles: 5, posts: [
        {postId: 101, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content", replies:[
            {replyId: 1, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content"},
            {replyId: 2, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content"},
            {replyId: 3, contents: "Dummy content", author: "Dummy content"}
        ]},
    ]}
];  

var topicTable = $("<table class='forumTable'><tr><th>Title</th><th>Posts</th><th>Followers</th></tr></table>");

//console test
//console.log(topics);      

//Looping all topics in variable "topics"
for (index in topics) {
    //console test
    console.log(topics[index].title);
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append("<td>" + topics[index].title + "</td>");
    row.append("<td>" + topics[index].articles + "</td>");
    row.append("<td>" + topics[index].followers + "</td>");

    topicOnClick(row, topics[index]);                               
    topicTable.append(row);         
}

page.append(topicTable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've given I think there are a couple of options.

#### Option 1

You say if the use repetitively 'clicks' the forum page implying there's a click handler. You can use `.one` which executes the function at most on times.

```js
var table = "<table><tr><td>column1</td><td>column2</td></tr></table>";
$('button').one('click', function() {
  $('#tableContainer').append(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="tableContainer">
  </div>

  <button>add</button>
</body>
```

### Option 2

You could target the container div and use `.html()` this will allow the function to run on each click but will write over the content so it gives the appearance of only being loaded once.

```js
var table = "<table><tr><td>column 1</td><td>column 2</td></tr></table>";
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#tableContainer').html(table);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="tableContainer">
 </div>

<button>add</button>
</body>
```